# History of primality testing

Tags: mathematics, algorithm, primes

Consider a uniform random variable $n$ which is an integer in the interval $2^{1023} < n < 2^{1024}$. What is the oldest algorithm capable of determining whether or not $p$ is a probable prime and which could be executed in a reasonable amount of time in pen and paper by mathematicians of the day?

The oldest example I know of is Fermat's little theorem from 1640. Is there anything older?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [link](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Emoira/mat331-spr10/papers/2002%20MollinA%20Brief%20History%20of%20Factoring.pdf) for the paper "A Brief History of Factoring and Primality Testing B. C. (Before Computers)", Cataldi created a method for primality testing which was verified by Fermat. The following is an excerpt from the paper:

> In particular, his work "*Trattato del modo brevissimo di trovar la radice quadra delli numeri*"
> published in 1613, represents a significant contribution to the development of continued fractions. His work on perfect numbers was also considerable. Among his thirty
> 20 MATH EMATICS MAGAZI N E
> VOL. 75, NO. 1, FEBRUARY2002 21
> books, he wrote on military applications of algebra, and even published an edition of
> Euclid's Elements. Cataldi proved that the fifth, sixth, and seventh perfect numbers
> are:
>
> [image: Perfect Numbers]
>
> It is uncertain whether Cataldi was the first to discover these
> perfect numbers, but his are the first known proofs of these facts.
> Cataldi was also the first to observe that if 2n _ 1 is prime then n
> must be prime. In fact, the following result was known to Cataldi,
> though proved by Fermat.
>
> [image: Theorem 1]
>
> Long after Cataldi, Euler showed that every even perfect number has the form given
> in Theorem 1. It is unknown whether there are any odd perfect numbers and the search
> for them has exceeded the bound 10^300. Moreover, if such a beast exists, then it is
> known that it must have at least twenty-nine (not necessarily distinct) prime factors
> (see Guy [6, B l, p. 44]).

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm afraid I'm missing something.  Nowhere in this excerpt do I see any method for primality testing (the same is true for the section of the referenced book).